# error: lvalue required while operator overloading ++/-- etc

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, compiler-errors

I transferred my code to Ubuntu 4.4.1 g++ compiler. While overloading `operator ++ (int)` as below, it throws error for `(T*)`, but works fine for `(T*&)`. In my earlier version (linux-64, but don't remember exact version) it was working fine with `(T*)` also.

Any reason, **why** ?

```
template<typename T>
struct Wrap
{
  void *p;  // Actually 'p' comes from a non-template base class
  Wrap<T>& operator ++ ()
  {
    ((T*)p) ++;  // throws error; if changed to (T*&) then ok!
    return *this;
  }
// ...
};
int main ()
{
  Wrap<int> c;
  ++c;  // calling prefix increment
}
```

Comment: Did you mean for that to be `operator ++ (int)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A result of a type-cast is not an lvalue, so it cannot be assigned to and (built-in) ++ is a form of assignment. It was a bug in the compiler if it ever worked.

With reference it compiles (in efect it's the same as `*(T**)&p`), but due to aliasing rules (compiler may assume that pointers (and references) of different types don't point to the same object) it is formally invalid, though it will work on all known compilers.

The cleanest way it to:

```
p = static_cast<void *>(static_cast<T *>(p) + 1)
```

(never use C-style cast in C++) and rely on the compiler being able to compile it exactly the same way as `++`. However if you have the template argument available when defining the pointer (in the sample code you do), it's much better to just use properly typed pointer (I'd say it would also work with member pointers, but they don't have meaningful `++`).

Comment: Actually, the cleanest way would be to use `static_cast` and not `reinterpret_cast`, Void pointer conversions are supported by `static_cast` in C++.

Comment: @AndreyT: Thanks. I changed `reinterpret_cast` to `static_cast`.

Comment: `though it will work on all known compilers` Except g++ (at least).  It's very frequent for compilers to use the fact that pointers to different types can't alias.  (There's also the fact that pointers to different types may have different sizes and representations, but that's more a theoretical issue than a practical problem today.)

Comment: Actually `void* p;` is coming from a non-template base class; so I can not use `T* p;`. Why can't we use C-Style cast in known circumstances ? Also, why are you casting again `static_cast<void *>`, even though it will be implicitly casted to `void*` ?

Comment: @James: g++ tries to follow the specification to the letter, while most other compilers tend to allow cases that are not according to the specification, but programmer's intention is sufficiently clear.

Comment: @iammilind: Since casting to and from `void *` is always a bit dangerous in C++ (e.g. while cast from `Base *` to `Derived *` is always OK, casting from `Base *` to `void *` and from that to `Derived *` will fail miserably if multiple inheritance is involved), I like to be explicit about it (that's also why I don't like the fact `static_cast` supports it and would prefer if it required a `reinterpret_cast`)

Comment: @jan hudec I'm not sure it's a question of following the specification to the letter---g++ only gives a warning in such cases.  The problem is that the optimizer assumes that pointers to different types can't alias.  Which is correct up to a point (and other compilers do the same), but when the cast creating the alias is sitting there in front of it, in the same basic block... ignoring the alias in such cases can only be considered stubornness.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you mixing up your prefix and postfix increment signatures. Also, why use a void* if you know your type is T ?

See below for appropriate signatures:
http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=231051

Comment: The issue is with the commented line and that one is calling built-in operator++ on a plain old pointer! (I'd give you -1, but the link is useful, though it does not answer the main point)